# Error "SysError 0 during open of "AUResources.r"" When Compiling an AudioUnit

Tags: c++, core-audio

In the default AudioUnit project shell that XCode creates, there is a line at the very bottom of your AUEffect .r file:

```
#include "AUResources.r"
```

When compiling under Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard, this line causes the following error:

> SysError 0 during open of "AUResources.r"

Note, this error occurs in a completely empty project shell, ie, it's a bug in the XCode project template.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

XCode generated your project template targeted at the 10.5 platform, which has a different resource path that 10.6. Unhelpfully, the path names are silly:

- 10.6: /Developer/Extras/CoreAudio
- 10.5: /Developer/Examples/CoreAudio

To fix:

1. Get Info on the AUPublic folder in your project source, and change the Path to the correct CoreAudio/AudioUnit/AUPublic folder for your OS/Build target.
2. Get Info on every file in the Public Utility project folder and hange the paths to the the correct path for your OS. Yes, all of them.
3. Add the appropriate CAAutoDisposer.h file to the Public Utility project folder.
4. Do a Clean on the project to prevent [nasty vtable errors](http://forums.macosxhints.com/archive/index.php/t-34194.html)

Basic diagnosis from the [coreaudio-api listserv](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Coreaudio-api/2009/Nov/msg00271.html)

Comment: Using JUCE, I had to fix it into the Project > Targets > myPlugin > Build Settings > Search Paths > Header Search Path > update all the paths to the CoreAudio folder. Using the latest audio tools the new CoreAudio location is not in XCode anymore but in the "/Library/Developer/CoreAudio/" folder.